# How to write google business review API in custom module and call into phtml file

Tags: api, helper, magento2.4.1

What is the best approach to write google business review API in custom module and call inside the custom phtml file,

Eg Code:

```
<?php 
$accountId = 'your_account_id';
$locationId = 'your_location_id';

$url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$accountId.'/locations/'.$locationId.'/reviews';    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
/*If data is in xml format
$output = simplexml_load_string($output); */
$allData = json_decode(json_encode($output), TRUE); // You will get all the data
?>
```

How to call the google review thing into my custom phtml file?

I am getting values in Postman:

Url : https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789/locations/321654987/reviews using header authorization.

I want to display in my custom phtml page, how to write module for this?

Comment: The best approach is not to write the API calls in helper classes.

Comment: What is the best approach, how to include API code into my custom module then i need to call that thing into my phtml file?

Comment: @DianaBotean Can you pls help me with the best approach?